# How to separate integer in loop?

Tags: java

When I try to separate decimal from others it work fine with using ***boolean***.
But I doesn't work anymore after another integer come but.

***This code is not written by me***

```
 String str = "123/0.312/43";
        boolean b= false;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            if (b || str.charAt(i + 1) == '.'){
                b = true;
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
            } else {
                System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
            }
}
```

but it only work like this

```
1
2
3
/
0.312/43
```

The number 4 and 3 are another numbers so.
How could I return?

***THIS IS THE EXPECTED RESULT THANKS***

```
1
2
3
/
0.312
/
4
3
```

Comment: Good morning. What do you mean by "separate decimal from others"? What's the expected output for 123.0123, for example?

Comment: Do you want to separate the number into two portions like this :1230.33343 to 1230 and 33343

Comment: @SayokMajumder the result shouldbe like the final block

Comment: ```0.333``` for the given format you should also check the recurrence of the number after decimal. When there is no recurrence, the else block should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void splitDigits(String str) {
    boolean slash = false;

    for (String part : str.split("/")) {
        if (slash)
            System.out.println('/');

        slash = true;

        if (part.contains("."))
            System.out.println(part);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < part.length(); i++)
                System.out.println(part.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: but it only work if the number are the same in duplicate.

Comment: @realNameDoesn'tExist then do write you question more precisely.

Comment: sorry about that I will fix it then.

Comment: I just edit it can you please have a look